# oracle unlock HR account

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

hello i'm learning oracle and trying to unlock HR account
here's what happend to me
No rows Selected
why ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTJse.png)

Comment: what does this have to do with the HR account?

Comment: Hi @hasan taha, below you have the answer how to unlock the HR account, but I am afraid that you put the wrong picture on the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your picture you show you are connected with SYS. To unlock the HR account you have to use the ALTER USER ACCOUNT UNLOCK statement.

```
SQL> ALTER USER HR ACCOUNT UNLOCK ;
```

Then you'll be able to connect with HR to the database, if that is what you want. However, having the account locked **does not mean** you cannot access the objects owned by that account. I mean, HR is an example schema, but you can see any table owned by HR as long as you have privileges over it.

In your case, you are connecting with SYS, who is the superuser, so you can see literally  everything with that user:

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try following these steps:

1.Go to CMD(Command Prompt)

2.Execute following commands

3. SQLPLUS / AS SYSDBA
   inorder to connect to oracle database
4. ALTER USER HR ACCOUNT UNLOCK
   inorder to alter HR user and unlock

Try using the HR in the creation of connection

If the struggle is still there,try assigning another password to HR as follow

5. ALTER USER HR IDENTIFIED BY